# A differential maximization problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

OK, I know how to solve maximization problems on numbers, and I know how to solve differential equations which are equations on functions, but how do I solve a 'maximization problem' over functions?

Here is a specific problem:

> Find a positive real function $F(x)$, continuous and monotonically increasing on the real interval $[0,1]$, which maximizes:
>
> $$\frac{F(x)}{F(1)}$$
>
> Subject to:
>
> $$F'(x) = (1-x)F''(x)$$

what is the function $F$ which attains this maximum?

Comment: The exponential is not a solution of the equation !

Comment: You could try to solve the differential equation first. But it confuses me that the solution is not continuous at $1$. Did you copy the correct problem?

Comment: Does the differential condition only hold in the one point that you use to find the maximum? Or is this a kind of multi-optimal problem where you have to compute a Pareto front?

Comment: Actually, my original intention was that $F(x)/F(1)$ should be maximized where $x$ is the solution to the equation $F'(x)=(1-x)F''(x)$. I should have called it $x_0$. In any case, I will have to ask a new question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a separable differential equation
$$\frac{\left(F'(x)\right)'}{F'(x)}=\frac1{1-x},$$
i.e.
$$\ln\left(F'(x)\right)=C-\ln|1-x|,$$
$$F'(x)=\frac C{1-x},$$
$$F(x)=C\ln|1-x|+C'.$$
Due to the singularity at $1$, I don't see a better solution than a constant.

Answer (score 0):

For $x<1$, second equation yields
$$\frac {F''(x)}{F'(x)}=\frac1{1-x}$$
or, integrating
$$\ln F'(x)=-\ln(1-x)+C$$
and this implies
$$F'(x)=\frac K{1-x}$$
and integrating again,
$$F(x)=J-K\ln(1-x)$$

where $C,J\in\Bbb R$ and $K>0$.

Continuity of $F$ at $x=1$ implies
$$F(1)=\lim_{x\to1^-}\big(J-K\ln(1-x)\big)$$
but this limit is not finite, so the second equation can not be satisfied on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: $K>0$ is not required.